# Canonical reference for why not to use eval?

Tags: architecture, eval, software-design

The `eval` function (in JS, Python, etc.) is analogous to the `goto` statement:

- Sometimes useful.
- Rarely strictly necessary.
- Often considered to make code less readable and understandable.
- Discouraged or forbidden by many style guides for large codebases.

If you ask why `goto` is so maligned, you'll quickly be pointed to Dijkstra's famous [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Estorm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf). **Is there an equivalent canonical reference for `eval`?**

I don't want to have a discussion of the language constructs themselves - I know `goto` is encouraged for some patterns in Linux kernel code, `eval` is critical for module loaders, and so on - I'm asking about authoritative references in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find Djisktra paper on the `eval()`, but a little googling turned up a conference paper with the cute title:

[The Eval That Men Do](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22655-7_4)

by Gregor Richards, et al.

Google Scholar says the paper is cited over 260 times. Is that enough to be canonical?